# Should I see evidence of shared storage space on a family member account before they exceed 15GB?

Tags: google-drive, google-one

I just setup a family group, designating the family manager as an account with a 100GB Google Drive subscription and invited a family member to join the family group.

I am worried that I did not setup something correctly because I see no mention of the shared storage space on either account, but am not sure whether what I am experiencing is "normal".

Here is what the storage screen looks like form the family member's account
(Manage Account/Data & Personalization/Manage Storage)

[image]

Here is what the storage screen looks like form the family manager's account
(Manage Account/Data & Personalization/Manage Storage)

[image]

This is exactly what these screens looked like before I setup the family group. There is nothing I see on these screens that indicate the 100gb subscription is actually being shared.

But, it appears I successfully invited the family member to the family group:

[image]

Yet, on the "Manage Family Settings" screen on the Family Manager Account, I don't see "Google One" listed in the "What you are sharing" section, which makes me wonder if I need to do something else to explicitly enable sharing on Google One, but if that's the case I cannot find a setting to enable.

[image]

Does anyone know if it looks like my family group is setup properly to share Family Manager's 100GB Google Drive Subscription or if there is something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

As often occurs, I somehow stumbled on the answer after writing up a detailed question :-)

Answer: Google One must be specifically enabled.

1. Go to https://one.google.com/
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Manage Family Settings
4. Enable "Share Google One With Family"

[image]